# Make trapezoid from image

Tags: html, css

I want to make a trapezoid-filled picture, like this:

[image: Example]

I do not need to rotate. I do not need to tilt the picture. `transform: matrix` does not work!

Solution is almost found only need to connect the two pieces of code:

```
background-image:url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D9i-wqTIjFw/T5x_51p2rJI/AAAAAAAABLs/VytuZcJGNuY/s400/indahnya.jpg");
```

To this good code:

```
.myShape {
width: 0;
height: 50px;
border-left: 50px solid red;
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
```

}

Comment: I don't think that's possible with 2D transforms; you'd need `rotateY` with perspective.

Comment: For example, http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/GbDHn. You can do the same thing with any image.

Comment: Or do you mean you just want to crop the image to a trapezoid-shaped area?

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS, you can make such a shape. Try something like this:

```css
.myShape {
    width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 50px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jp769/)

Comment: Ok. Just litlle detail: how add property that it works : background-image:url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D9i-wqTIjFw/T5x_51p2rJI/AAAAAAAABLs/VytuZcJGNuY/s400/indahnya.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of doing that with an image is to use 3D transforms with perspective. So on your element, you'd need to give it a rotation on the y-axis:

```css
#rectangle {
    background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D9i-wqTIjFw/T5x_51p2rJI/AAAAAAAABLs/VytuZcJGNuY/s400/indahnya.jpg");
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
            transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

And then give some value of `perspective` to a parent.

[Here's a demo!](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/GbDHn)

Comment: @JonMaximys: It doesn't until 15.0. Nothing you can do about that, really…